# How to mock RxJS Subject and call next method in Angular unit-test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I trying to mock RxJS Subject which is property of service. This service is calling as dependency injection in class component constructor. I have two methods **storeProduct()** && **responseHandler()** so inside the responseHandler method I`m subscribe for this subject. So I try to write unit tests for those two methods but I can not mock this subject and call him next method.I need help to see what I doing wrong.

Here is my code:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UtilsService } from './services/utils.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
message!: string;

constructor(private utilsService: UtilsService) { }

storeProduct() {
  this.utilsService.storeProductDetails();
  this.responseHandler();
}

responseHandler() {
  this.utilsService._httpResponse$.subscribe(({ message }) => {
  this.message = message;
  });
 }
}
```

utils.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { CoreService } from './core.service';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UtilsService {
  _httpResponse$ = new Subject<any>()
  constructor(private coreService: CoreService) { }

  storeProductDetails() {
    this.coreService.storeProductDetails().subscribe(res => {
    this.httpResponse(res.content, null);
  })
 }

  httpResponse(content: any, errors: any) {
  this._httpResponse$.next({
    message: content,
    errors: errors
  });
 }
}
```

core.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CoreService {
  storeProductDetails(): Observable<any> {
    return of({ content: 'Product was stored succesffuly' });
  }
}
```

app.component.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreService } from './services/core.service';
import { UtilsService } from './services/utils.service';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let app: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let coreServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<CoreService>;
  let utilsService: UtilsService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    coreServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('CoreService', ['storeProductDetails']);

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: CoreService,
          useValue: coreServiceSpy
        }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    utilsService = TestBed.inject(UtilsService);
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
   app = fixture.componentInstance;
 })

  it('should store product details succesful and show message', () => {
    coreServiceSpy.storeProductDetails.and.returnValue(of({ content: 'The product details was stored succesful.' }))
    utilsService._httpResponse$.next({ message: 'The product details was stored succesful.', errors: null });
    fixture.detectChanges();
    app.storeProduct();
    expect(app.message).toEqual('The product details was stored succesful.');
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Your TesbBed might be missing a mock for the utilsservice. Can you tell the errormessage being awoked when running the test in order to clearify the specific problem?

Comment: The error is Expected undefined to equal 'The product details was stored succesful.'.

Comment: have you tried to first call `app.storeProduct();` and then afterwards to run the `fixture.detectChanges();` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a issue with your `utilsService._httpResponse$.next`
being called within the test, relating to the error message posted in screenshot.

I find it easier to just mock out your services using plain objects, modeling your service class (objects containing your jasmine spies).

A approach similar to this, hope it helps:

```
mockCoreService = {
    getMessage:jasmine.createSpy('openConfirmModal').and.returnValue(
     of({ content: 'The product details was stored successful.' }))
    }

mockUtilsService = {
   _httpResponse$: new Subject<any>() /// Or of(message: content, errors:errors), 
   httpResponse : jasmine.createSpy('httpResponse').and...
   storeProductDetails: jasmine.createSpy('storeProductDetails').and...
}
```

Then just pass the mock objects as providers

```
providers: [
        {
          provide: CoreService,
          useValue: mockCoreService
        },
        {
          provide: UtilsService,
          useValue: mockUtilService
        }
      ]
```

Comment: Hi, I understand about the mockUtilsService but for mockCoreService I dont't have those getMessage and openConfirmModal method there. So what I did is to replace getMessage with storeProductDetails and the test doesn't pass again. I tried to replace the subject with behaviorsubject and the test pass. I really don't udnerstant what is the problem with the subject...., If is not problem for you can you provide me the wholе code for app.component.spec.ts

Comment: ` I tried to replace the subject with behaviorsubject and the test pass.`
I see, yeah I think that might work because behaviorsubject takes a default value on creation.
So I think there might be a issue with the async behavior within the services/test, but not sure to be 100% honest.
.
I would also try moving the:
`coreServiceSpy.storeProductDetails.and.returnValue` and `utilsService._httpResponse$.next(....` 
Outside the test, and place above into the Describe or BeforeEach area.